# In C/C++ and Java, why does dividing an integer by an integer return an integer, while in other languages, it returns a decimal value?

Tags: operators

I have found [another similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307993/why-does-integer-division-result-in-an-integer), but the answer there talks mainly about C/C++, and does not mention about the division operator. So, in C/C++ and Java, dividing an integer by an integer returns an integer. On the other hand, in Python, a single slash will return a floating point while a double slash will return an integer. What is the historical factor of the result of division operator?

Comment: Why should it be the same?

Comment: Every language can make up its own rules. Some languages tend to be more human-oriented and have division always return a float or fraction, others tend to be more machine-oriented and use integer division. The latter is attractive because it is more orthogonal (if you want float division you can convert the operands yourself) and because there is a performance difference, especially historically or on embedded systems that don't have an FPU. Float division may lose precision. In a language where the division operator is float-only, there might be an integer division library function instead.

Comment: IIRC, in these higher level languages, there's no integer type. There's just number which is an 'integer' if it happens to be all zeros after the decimal point. However lower level languages have a distinct type for integers and floats so it would not make sense for division between integers to return a different type.

Comment: Division is lossy unless a rational number is returned. What a language is doing by choosing float vs decimal is deciding if they are catering to scientists vs accountants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a language design decision.  In Java, it was likely because that's the way it works in C.  I initially said that Guido van Rossum made a different choice for Python but that's wrong, it was [a change made in Python 3](https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/) (thanks Alexander the 1st.)  As described in [PEP 238](https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/):

> The classic division operator makes it hard to write numerical expressions that are supposed to give correct results from arbitrary numerical inputs.

Later it explains why this is not an issue in some languages:

> The problem is unique to dynamically typed languages: in a statically typed language like C, the inputs, typically function arguments, would be declared as double or float, and when a call passes an integer argument, it is converted to double or float at the time of the call. Python doesn’t have argument type declarations, so integer arguments can easily find their way into an expression.

The truncated approach in C is useful for pointer arithmetic.  It makes a lot of sense in that context.  There's also a satisfying complementary relationship between division and modulus in this scheme.

Comment: And in Smalltalk, for example, it will neither result in an integer nor a float, but in a rational.

Comment: I'll add that the Python "Int divided by Int = Float" is relatively new, even for Python - [Python 2.x used the "Int divided by Int = Int" approach, and it's 3.x that changed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/integer-division-in-python-2-and-python-3).

Comment: (On that note, the documentation of the change can be found [here, in PEP-238](https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/)).

Comment: The tl;dr; is that Python doesn't have integer *variables*, only integer *objects*. In python 2.x you can't tell what `a/b` means. In C and Java you can look at the declaration of `a` and `b` to know the type.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st Thanks for that.  I'll update the answer.